# Trying to make a menu in HTML, how do i upload a local photo and use the link in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu for the code I've written but no matter what i change i still can't get it working. I'm a total beginner so I don't really know my way around HTML very well. I want the menu to use an icon, on which when I click, the menu would appear. Also I want the items in the menu to have another dropdown menu for themselves. Please help.

One other problem i have is that i have made an icon for each list item to have behind it. I want to make it have an online url so that anyone who views the page could see it. I tried to upload the file to websites like imgur and use the link to link the icon to my code but it doesnt work. it works fine when i link it locally but not online. What do i do?

I'm sorry if i can't provide my code properly i just don't know what to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/siR2l.jpg

Edit:guys I leaned that it's a lot easier to do toemthinf like this with Java script and I should wait until I learn that. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to include your actual code (not images of code). [Creating a 
 snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) will also help you include your code with the question.

Comment: Try My Answer Its Helpfull

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

This shows how to do vertical or horizontal menus.
If you want an image per line, you need to add a background-image to the link with CSS.

---

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

This is the brief idea of how the "img" tag work in html.

https://html.com/attributes/img-src/#Relative_URLs

An example of how the "img" src is called in  an absolute URL and a relative URL is shown here. If your image isn't showing up it is probably have to do with your link. In your image above, your "img" src doesn't end with a .png, .jpg (image file extension) that is why your image isn't showing up in the webpage.